# Retrieve GET parameters as is without replacing '+' sign with " "

Tags: django, angularjs, http

I am working with an API provider that sends me some kind of token in one of the responses.

The token looks something like this: `SomE73ThiL1k3T+ashR`

Now I take this from my angularJs front end and using `$resource` I send it to my Django's backend:

```
var res = SomeResource({
                    tokenName : SomE73ThiL1k3T+ashR,
                       }, function(){
console.log(res);
})
```

But when I do this at the back:

```
    request.GET.get("tokenName")
```

the "+" gets replaced by a white space and it looks like this: `"SomE73ThiL1k3T ashR"`

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent();`

```
var res = SomeResource({
    tokenName : encodeURIComponent("SomE73ThiL1k3T+ashR"),
}, function() {
    console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = SomeResource({
                    tokenName : SomE73ThiL1k3T%2BashR,
                       }, function(){
console.log(res);
})
```

Change **+** with **%2B**